# NullPointerException when trying to pass an Object through "this"

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, javafx, this

I was doing this tutorial in JavaFX and got a null pointer exception on the line marked by " <<--NullPointerException". I just couldnt understand why this is happening. Any help? The method to which "this" goes is also given. The rest of codes are pretty much correct Im sure. The error description is also given.

```
public class MainApp extends Application{

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private BorderPane rootLayout;
    private ObservableList<Person> personData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


    public MainApp() {
        personData.add(new Person("Stefan", "Meier"));
        personData.add(new Person("Martin", "Mueller"));
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("AddressApp");
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("sample.fxml"));
            rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException iox){
            iox.printStackTrace();
        }

        showPersonOverview();
    }

    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }

    public void showPersonOverview() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("fxcontroller.fxml"));
            AnchorPane overviewPage = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            rootLayout.setCenter(overviewPage);

            // Give the controller access to the main app
            Controller controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMainApp(this); // <<--NullPointerException

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ObservableList<Person> getPersonData(){
      return personData;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

method setMainApp() in Class Controller. The other codes in this class is correct that I'm sure as most are just set and get or create buttons and labels.

```
@FXML
private TableView<Person> personTable;

private MainApp mainApp;

public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
    this.mainApp = mainApp;

    personTable.setItems(mainApp.getPersonData());
}
```

This is first portion of fxcontroller.fxml file which gives AnchorPane

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

//import statements

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   .....
```

The error message:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

    ....

Caused by: **java.lang.NullPointerException**

    ....
```

Sorry to make the description too long. I wish I knew how to make it shorter.

Comment: Your `controller` variable is likely null. That would cause the NPE you are seeing.

Comment: @forgivenson is correct. Can you post (at least the root element of) your `fxcontroller.fxml` file?

Comment: `MainApp.java:69` check here your object is null

Comment: I suspected that controller variable is null but Ive been trying to figure out why 'loader.getController()' is not returning anything.System failure maybe? Previously the error was on that line.

Comment: maybe there is no "personTable" in the fxml File? There has to be a <TableView fx:id="personTable" ...>

Comment: yes there is fx:id="personTable" and fx:ids for every other tables. The error didnt show when I manually set all the 'fx:id' for each table and labels. But I still dont understand why loader.getController() return null when I dont do the above.

Comment: Well it basically looks correct to me. I would put a `System.out.println(controller);` in there, just to verify that the controller really is `null`. Then check that you really are loading the latest version of your FXML file. You are initializing the loader in a slightly nonstandard way: typically you would do `new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(...))` instead of getting a system resource.

Comment: wow of i never thought of it. Great idea. Thanks James.
Also, I think I solved it somehow when I put the "fx:id" to all the buttons and labels in the "fxcontroller,fxml" file. Somehow, I still dont understand why.

Answer (score -1):

Your controller cannot be loaded. That's why you get nullpointerexception.

1. may be controller path is wrong
2. or you did some mistake to specify controller in fxml file